# Prolog Filter out array of numbers

Tags: prolog

doing prolog as an assignment, and trying to filter array of numbers. I have the following code to filter out all elements lesser than 5 and output the array with remaining numbers. The problem I have is I can't change 5 with something else.

```
delete_smaller([], []).
delete_smaller([Head|Tail], List) :- 
    (  Head < 5
    -> List = Output 
    ;  List = [Head|Output] 
    ), 
    delete_smaller(Tail, Output).
```

Current situation:

```
?- delete_smaller([1,2,3,4,7,8], Output).
Output = [7, 8]
```

Desired situation:
?- delete_smaller([1,2,3,4,7,8], 5, Output).
Output = [7, 8]

with a very limited knowledge of prolog intuitively I attempted to do following:

```
delete_smaller([], []).
delete_smaller([Head|Tail], Target, List) :- 
    (  Head < Target
    -> List = Output 
    ;  List = [Head|Output] 
    ), 
    delete_smaller(Tail, Target, Output).
```

However with

```
?- delete_smaller(Tail, Target, Output).
```

query I receive false

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: You forgot to modify the first clause, which is the base case for the recursion. You should add the missing argument between those empty lists.

Comment: this is the answer, thank you!

Comment: @gusbro Can you add the correct answer as an answer so we can see this has an accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to modify the first clause of your procedure (the base case of the recursion).

You added another parameter (the `Target`) to `delete_smaller/2` so now it becomes `delete_smaller/3`; all your clauses should be accordingly modified.
As you are don't care for the value of the `Target` in the base case, just use an anonymous variable (`_`) as the second parameter:

```
delete_smaller([], _, []).
delete_smaller([Head|Tail], Target, List) :- 
    (  Head < Target
    -> List = Output 
    ;  List = [Head|Output] 
    ), 
    delete_smaller(Tail, Target, Output).
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
delete_smaller( []     , _ ,    []  ) .
delete_smaller( [X|Xs] , N ,    Ys  ) :- H <  N , delete_smaller(Xs,N,Ys) .
delete_smaller( [X|Xs] , N , [X|Ys] ) :- H >= N , delete_smaller(Xs,N,Ys) .
```

You'll find that your predicates become easier to understand and simpler if you implementing alternatives via the use of additional clauses in your predicate (as above) or by refactoring to smaller, more discrete predicates, rather than using the `;` alternative operator.

Another way one could do this might be to create a predicate like this, that takes a value, compares to a limit value and prepends it to the result list and gives back the tail:

```
filter( X , N ,    Xs  , Xs ) :- X <  N .
filter( X , N , [X|Xs] , Xs ) :- X >= N .
```

Once you have that, then your `delete_smaller/3` gets even simpler:

```
delete_smaller( []     , _ , [] ) .
delete_smaller( [X|Xs] , N , Ys ) :- filter(X,N,Ys,Zs), delete_smaller(Xs,N,Zs) .
```

For this problem, this is overkill, but this sort of relentless refactoring make for code that's easier to test as your components are smaller and simpler.